# NetLogo: How to make a turtle recognise any shade of one color?

Tags: netlogo

I'm using NetLogo for the first time and need to lay out a simple programme where i have one light source that diffuses light out beyond its source patch and one turtle that will avoid the light.

I can achieve this by using basic 'set pcolor yellow' and then use 'if patch-ahead [pcolor] = yellow [right 45][fd speed]' type command. However this doesn't give me diffused light.

By adapting the HeatBugs code, i can diffuse the color out past the source patch, however the roaming turtle no longer recognises the color as yellow, i think, as it is a scale-color. I tried setting the code to != black but this also doesn't work. I'm assuming it's because the patches are being recolored after each tick.

Is there a way to make the turtle recognise the patches of diffused color so as to avoid them? Or a simpler way to diffuse the light out. (i want a variable intensity so using neighbors and yellow -1 won't do it.)

Here's the code i have so far: (this is a condensed version as i have other things happening in the main body, so i apologise if it isn't clear)

```
globals [ color-by-unhappiness? ]

turtles-own[
  speed
  speed-limit
  speed-min
  ideal-temp       ;; The temperature I want to be at
  output-heat      ;; How much heat I emit per time step
  unhappiness      ;; The magnitude of the difference between my ideal
               ;;   temperature and the actual current temperature here
]

patches-own[
  temp           
]

to setup
  clear-all
  setup-turtles
  ;;creating diffused light
  set color-by-unhappiness? false ;; button
  ask n-of number-of-lights patches [
    sprout 1 [
      set color white
      set shape "circle"
      set ideal-temp  min-ideal-temp  + random (max-ideal-temp  - min-    ideal-temp) ;;these are all sliders
      set output-heat min-output-heat + random (max-output-heat - min-  output-heat) ;;these are all sliders
      set unhappiness abs (ideal-temp - temp) ;;ideal-temp is a button
      color-by-ideal-temp
      set size 2
    ]
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to setup-turtles
  create-fears number-of-fears [
    set color violet
    set shape "circle"
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set speed 0.1 + random-float 0.9
    set speed-limit 1
    set speed-min 0.00
  ]
end

to go
  ask turtles [
    if speed > speed-limit [set speed speed-limit]
    fd speed
  ask fears[
    if patch-ahead 1 = nobody [rt 135]
    if patch-right-and-ahead 45 1 != nobody and [pcolor] of patch-right-and-ahead 45 1 != black[left 45]
    if patch-left-and-ahead 45 1 != nobody and [pcolor] of patch-left-and-ahead 45 1 != black[right 45]
    ifelse [pcolor] of patch-here = yellow [set speed speed-min][fd speed]
  ]
  if not any? turtles [ stop ]
  ;; diffuse heat through world
  diffuse temp diffusion-rate
  ask patches [ set temp temp * (1 - evaporation-rate) ]
  ask turtles [ set temp temp + output-heat ask bugs [bug-move patch-here]]
  recolor-turtles
  recolor-patches
  tick
end

to recolor-patches
  ask patches [ set pcolor scale-color yellow temp 0 150 ]
]
end
```

Comment: http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#shade-of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't use your code as-is; check out the [MCVE guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for some tips on reducing your code to just the necessary parts.

Color in Netlogo can given as a string, but it's also just a range of numbers. If you look at Tools > Color Swatches, you will see that the range of "Yellow" colors corresponds roughly to 40 ~ 50. So if you want to, you can just have them evaluate patch color using a numerical range rather than the color name. So, using this unnecessarily complicated example setup:

```
patches-own [ light? temp]

to setup
  ca
  ask patches [ 
    set light? false
  ]
  ask n-of 5 patches [
    set light? true
    set temp 150
  ]
  recolor-patches
  crt 10 [
    move-to one-of patches with [ not ( pcolor > 40 and pcolor < 49 ) ]
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to recolor-patches
  ask n-of 3 patches with [ light? ] [
    if temp < 20 [
      set temp temp + random 20
    ]
  ]
  repeat 5 [
    diffuse temp 0.1
  ]
  ask patches [ 
    ifelse temp > 0.25 [
      set temp temp - 0.005
    ] [
      set temp 0
    ]
    set pcolor scale-color yellow temp 0 15
  ]
end
```

You can ask your turtles to move and just avoid patches that fall in that numerical range:

```
to go
  recolor-patches
  ask turtles [
    ifelse [pcolor] of patch-ahead 1 > 40 and [pcolor] of patch-ahead 1 < 49 [
      let target min-one-of neighbors [pcolor]
      if target != nobody [
        face target 
        fd 1
      ]
    ] [
      rt random 60 - 30 
      fd 1
    ]
  ]
  tick
end
```

**EDIT**

As Seth Tisue [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/users/86485/seth-tisue), the `shade-of?` primitive can accomplish what the greater than / less than logical statement does:

```
to go
  recolor-patches
  ask turtles [
    ifelse shade-of? ( [pcolor] of patch-ahead 1 ) yellow [
      let target min-one-of neighbors [pcolor]
      if target != nobody [
        face target
        fd 1
      ]
    ] [
      rt random 60 - 30
      fd 1
    ]
  ]
  tick
end
```

However, this does require a slight modification to the `recolor-patches` procedure, as `scale-color` sets the base color to 40 (in the case of 'yellow'); just ask patches with that `pcolor` to set their color to black (0) so that movement works as expected here:

```
to recolor-patches
  ask n-of 3 patches with [ light? ] [
    if temp < 20 [
      set temp temp + random 20
    ]
  ]
  repeat 5 [
    diffuse temp 0.1
  ]
  ask patches [
    ifelse temp > 0.25 [
      set temp temp - 0.005
    ] [
      set temp 0
    ]
    set pcolor scale-color yellow temp 0 15
    if pcolor = 40 [
      set pcolor black
    ]
  ]
end
```

Comment: NetLogo has a `shade-of?` primitive which is helpful here.

Comment: @SethTisue - thank you for pointing that out, I have edited my answer to include that option.

Comment: I apologise for not responding sooner. This really helped and the shade-of?primitive was perfect for what i needed.